# Is there a way to create Admob ad units in bulk/through API?

Tags: google-api, admob, ads

We're trying to find a way to create Admob ad units in bulk, either through the dashboard (uploading some text file with preconfigured values for each ad unit or through some google API).

Is there any way to do that?
I looked through the documentation of Admob's API but I can't find any methods that allow changing/adding the data.

I can't find anything in the Admob dashboard either, I have to create mutliple ad units manually, sometimes hundreds of them per app.

Answer (score 0):

You can bulk upload csv file with https://admanager.google.com

Or use the Ad Manager API for adding more than 1,000 ad units at one time.

Reference -

1. https://support.google.com/admanager/answer/7029965?hl=en
2. https://support.google.com/admanager/answer/3088588